# Can I use a scrolling element within a Google Map with option scrollwheel: true?

Tags: google-maps

I have a Google map with the option **scrollwheel: true**

I'm adding an OverlayView into the Google map that contains HTML with scrollable content.  When I hover/click into the OverlayView, the mouse scrollwheel continues to zoom the Google map rather than scrolling the content of the Overlayview.

How do I prevent this behavior from occurring?

I've tried changing the options of the Google map to **scrollwheel: false** as an onclick event of the OverlayView, but this doesn't appear to trigger.

Answer (score 2):

InfoWindow was probably the correct approach to resolving this, but it wasn't a route we wanted to follow, since it would have meant significantly changing our code to handle InfoWindows within the OverlayView.

Instead we ended up adding listeners for the mouseover and mouseout events on the OverlayView, then toggled the Google Map and page behavior based upon the mouse events:

```
        // Prevent page body and google map from handling the mouse
        // Wheel events when hovering over pin group content
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(groupDiv, 'mouseover', function () {
            gMap.setOptions({
                disableDoubleClickZoom: true,
                navigationControl: false,
                scaleControl: false,
                draggable: false
            });
            $('html').css('overflow', 'hidden');
        })

        // Restore control to page body page body and google map 
        // when user is no longer hovering pin group content
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(groupDiv, 'mouseout', function () {
            gMap.setOptions({
                disableDoubleClickZoom: false,
                navigationControl: true,
                scaleControl: true,
                draggable: true
            });
            $('html').css('overflow', 'auto');
        })
```

Answer (score 1):

You can put your HTML content in an InfoWindow and use `gestureHandling : "greedy"` on your map so that the zoom can be controlled when the cursor is on the map, but not when on the InfoWindow. (Infowindow content is still scrollable)

Sample Fiddle :
https://jsfiddle.net/471fmzyv/

```
function initMap() {
  var uluru = {lat: -25.363, lng: 131.044};
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 4,
    center: uluru,
    gestureHandling : "greedy"
  });
```